# C++ Compiler Error (trying to create a static vector of vectors)

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create a static vector-of-vectors and I'm finding that the following code compiles and runs under gcc-4.1.2 but under gcc-4.5.1 it fails to compile with the message

```
assign.cxx:19:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘to(boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::basic_string<char> >&)’
```

Can anyone explain why this happens? If you have any other suggestions about how to do what I'm trying to do then I'd be happy with that instead :).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

template <template <typename> class containerType, typename elemType>
containerType<elemType> to( boost::assign_detail::generic_list<elemType> list ) {
  containerType<elemType> tempContainer = list;
  return tempContainer;
}

static const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > names = boost::assign::list_of
  (to<std::vector>(boost::assign::list_of<std::string>("A")("B")("C") ))
  (to<std::vector>(boost::assign::list_of<std::string>("D")("E")("F") ));

int main() {

  for( std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >::const_iterator itVec = names.begin(); itVec != names.end(); ++itVec ) {
    for( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator itStr = itVec->begin(); itStr != itVec->end(); ++itStr ) {
      std::cout << "Value is " << *itStr << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I *think* your explicit argument to `to` annoyingly has to be `std::vector<std::string>`, but I'm not sure. Give it a go.

Comment: @Tomalak: No, the template argument list is `template <typename> class Container, ...` which means that the first argument has to be a template, not a type. `std::vector<std::string>` is an specialization and thus a type, no longer a template.

Comment: @David: I think my comment said the same thing as your answer, except forgetting to change the template parameter list. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful replies (especially @dribeas). I've just realised that explicitly using `boost::assign::list_of< std::vector<std::string> >` and `boost::assign::list_of<std::string>` removes the need for the the templated function (it's nice to know how to do it though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that in your definition of `to<>()`, `containerType` is declared to have only one template parameter, when in fact `std::vector<>` has two template parameters.

The fact that this compiles in GCC 4.1.2 only indicates a bug in GCC 4.1.2 -- the code is still inherently incorrect.

Unfortunately, I can't think of a *good* workaround offhand. The following compiles but restricts you to containers with only two template arguments (wherein the second is the allocator), which may not be what you ultimately want:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

template<
  template<typename, typename> class containerType,
  typename allocatorType,
  typename elemType
>
containerType<elemType, allocatorType >
to(boost::assign_detail::generic_list<elemType> const& list)
{
  return list; // no need to explicitly construct a containerType instance
}

template<template<typename, typename> class containerType, typename elemType>
containerType<elemType, std::allocator<elemType> >
to(boost::assign_detail::generic_list<elemType> const& list)
{
  return to<containerType, std::allocator<elemType> >(list);
}

static std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > names = boost::assign::list_of
  (to<std::vector>(boost::assign::list_of<std::string>("A")("B")("C")))
  (to<std::vector>(boost::assign::list_of<std::string>("D")("E")("F")));

int main()
{
  typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::const_iterator outer_iter_t;
  typedef std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator inner_iter_t;

  for (outer_iter_t itVec = names.begin(); itVec != names.end(); ++itVec)
    for (inner_iter_t itStr = itVec->begin(); itStr != itVec->end(); ++itStr)
      std::cout << "Value is " << *itStr << '\n';
}
```

---

**EDIT** (in response to dribeas' comment): Updated to allow the caller to override the default allocator.

Comment: For the allocator problem, you could provide two versions of the template function, one taking an extra allocator template parameter that contains the implementation, and a different overload that calls the previous one injecting `std::allocator<elemType>` as allocator type.

Comment: @David : Good point, edited. However, the restriction that the container can only have two template parameters is still in effect.

Comment: I have just edited the code, the standard does not require that the `Allocator` type argument *must* be the instantiation of the template, so this solution shouldn't either. Code that might use a non-templated allocator: `std::vector<int, my_allocator> v` can just pass that type into the first version of `to<>`, which is slightly less constrained.

Comment: On the two arguments: the three common containers for which `list_of` is more commonly used fall within that category, so the solution is probably more than enough for the problem at hand. If the user needs more arguments, they already know the path for extension... more template arguments! :)

Answer (score 1):

After going around the problem a couple of things, I believe that the simplest solution is not using a template template argument, but rather a type template argument:

```
template <typename containerType, typename elemType>
containerType to( boost::assign_detail::generic_list<elemType> list ) {
  containerType tempContainer = list;
  return tempContainer;
}

static const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > names = boost::assign::list_of
  (to<std::vector<std::string> >(boost::assign::list_of<std::string>("A")("B")("C") ))
  (to<std::vector<std::string> >(boost::assign::list_of<std::string>("D")("E")("F") ));
```

It might require a bit more typing in the calling side, but it will take care of the extra template arguments that you are not declaring in your template template argument.

Answer (score -1):

Your call to the function `to<std::vector>( ... )` only contains one template parameter, whereas you function declaration contains two. I would try: `to<std::vector, std::string>( ... )`

Comment: I'm sure the intention is for the second parameter to be deduced, and I can't see why it wouldn't be.